# Need to push Notification only to Recipient's device not the Sender's

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am really stuck and want to push notification only to specific user using Firebase. I know the FCM method and have got the token. But this tutorial or other tutorials that I've followed are making me send push notification to both users including the sender. I just want to get notification on Recipient Device. Its been a long day , I've been working on this problem.
Looking for some key or UID of the Recipient now. Is it to be fetched from token that I have : `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`

Update : I am not able to store and retrieve token (device token) and other children and also am able to log the message in firebase "Functions" tab , but still not able to push the notification to the device . I am testing it on emulator .Should I test it on real device ?

My Node.js code:

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

 var rootRef = 
 functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}');

  exports.sendNotification = rootRef.onWrite(event => {


  const user_id = event.params.user_id;
  const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

  var request = event.data.val();

  var payload = {
    data: {
      title : "New Message from ",
      body: "userName has sent you message",
      icon: "default",
    }
  };

console.log('We have a notification for device token: ', user_id );
console.log('Checking if getting inside the node -- ', request.user );


 admin.messaging().sendToDevice(user_id, payload)
.then(function(response){
    console.log('This was the notification Feature',response);    
 })
 .catch(function(error){
    console.log('Error sending message ',error);      

  })

 })
```

MyFirebaseMEssagingService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService 
{
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and 
        notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result 
        of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        //remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            Map<String,String> payload = remoteMessage.getData();
            //            String title = 
            remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            //            String message = 
            remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            //        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Title : " + title);
            //        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + message);
            System.out.println("Messaging Service : Title - " + payload.get("title") 
            + " , body - " + payload.get("body"));
            sendNotification(payload);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages(){

    }

    private void sendNotification(Map<String,String> payload){

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new 
                NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Firebase Push 
                Notification"+payload.get("title"));
                builder.setContentText("Notification Text : "+ payload.get("body"));
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatWindow.class);
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
                        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
                        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }

}
```

FirebaseIDService.java:

```
public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        DatabaseReference firebase ;//= new Firebase("https://materialtabs-
        b5734.firebaseio.com//messages");
        firebase = 
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://materialtabs-
                b5734.firebaseio.com//notifications/");

                // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's 
                servers.
                sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any 
     server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
        System.out.println("Reading Token : "+ token);
    }
}
```

And I am starting my 'MyFirebaseMessagingService.java' inside my MainActivity file in "onCreate()"
 as "startService(new Intent(this, MyFirebaseMessagingService.class));"

Please help me. I think I am missing some minor details or it could be major, not sure !

Comment: Please, show your code.

Comment: Hey ! i updated my question..Could you take a look to it . Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need to store the firebase token of the recipient's device and then whenever you want to send the notification to the recipient you have to retrieve the token of the recipient's from the database and then you can send the notification using that token to the only recipient.

Comment: Hey, I am storing the token which I understand it as device token to the database and am able to get the console message and token at firebase but still not able to push notification to the device. 
I am testing my code on emulator , should I test it on real device ?

My node.js code :

Comment: Yeah, you need to test in a real device. I am really sorry for late reply.